# CSS :hover over two elements at the same position

Tags: css, hover

in that code  when i try to change the style of two divs positioned on the same place with :hover selector it only affects one div. I try with z-index, but dont work. How can i :hover the two divs at the same time? Thanks!

```
http://jsfiddle.net/CqhLr/1/
```

I need to get active the two hover at the same time

```
#text1:hover #text2#hover
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `:hover` to your containing div (#button) instead of each of the inner divs: http://jsfiddle.net/CqhLr/3/, so change your current hovers to look like this:

```
#button:hover #text1 {
    opacity: 0;
}
#button:hover #text2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my pen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEAvg

Move #text2 above #text1, add z-indexes, and change the selectors in the hovers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the sibling selector [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/CqhLr/4/), [More information on siblings](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

```
#text1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:10;
}
#text1:hover + #text2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
#text1:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```